# tools for 2d animation video

Tags: video

I don't know if here is the right place to ask that so sorry if I am wrong.
I just want to know wich tools do you use to make a video (or presentation) like this one :

I like the idea of 2D animation in this style, but I don't know wich are the best tools for creating something like this (I know that this is a big company and probably has some really good artistic guys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) is the preferred tool for motion graphics work like in this film.